# How to filter out photos and only have video files visible on Apple iPhone on default Microsoft Photos in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, iphone, photos, microsoft, app

How to filter out photos and only have video files visible on Apple iPhone on default Microsoft Photos in Windows?

As you can see from this image the external device I selected is my Apple Iphone but I am not able to filter out image files so that only video files are visible which would make it a lot easier to find the video files I want to import from my phone to my computer.

Is there a way to accomplish this so I don't have to go scrolling through image files just to find video files?

[image: Microsoft Windows Default Photos App Screenshot 1]

Also how do I change the destination for the videos or photos imported from the iPhone to the computer?

For me it defaults to Pictures.

I have created a new folder to where I want the video files to go to, but I have to manually select it each time I click the "add image" button which then brings me to the import destination option window.

I don't want to have to do this manually, I want the folder I created to be set as the default.

[image: Microsoft Windows Default Photos App Screenshot 2]

[I dont see a set to default?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUff1.png)